# How to use order by on the basis of 3 condtiton

Tags: asp.net, odbc

I am working on an application in asp.net window application whose data stored in excel sheet.
I have a sheet in excel:
Sheet2(STATE,Point)
on the basis of points the each state gets medals which has following criteria:-
Gold   : 7 points
Silver : 5 Points
Bronze : 4 Points

I want total medal of each STATE on the basis of their medals type means the STATE having most gold medal should be top.If 2 STATE have same number of Gold then the STATE having more silver medals should be on higher position.And if 2 STATE have same number of silver medals then the STATE having more Bronze medals should be on higher position. I have done following query:-

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportTech"].ConnectionString);
//string query = "select STATE,sum(Point) as MEDAL from [Sheet2$] Group by STATE order by sum(Point) desc";
//string query = "SELECT STATE,SUM(Point) AS MEDAL,(CASE Point == 7: 1 END) AS GoldCount FROM [Sheet2$] GROUP BY STATE ORDER BY SUM(Point) DESC";
string query = "select STATE,sum(Point) as MEDAL, sum(IIF(point = 7,1,0)) as Gold, sum(IIF(point = 5,1,0)) as Silver, sum(IIF(point = 4,1,0)) as Bronce from [Sheet2$] group by STATE order by sum(IIF(point = 7,1,0)) desc";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
```

but the query is not working if 2 STATE having similar Gold or Silver medals.kindly help me..Thanx

Comment: I applied code formatting because it was a genuine mess to figure out.

Comment: It is now Formatted.Now kindly help me in solving this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your calculations for the medals works, you should be able to simply add the extra arguments to the ORDER BY clause as so:

```
string query = "select STATE,sum(Point) as MEDAL, sum(IIF(point = 7,1,0)) as Gold, sum(IIF(point = 5,1,0)) as Silver, sum(IIF(point = 4,1,0)) as Bronce from [Sheet2$] group by STATE order by sum(IIF(point = 7,1,0)) desc,  sum(IIF(point = 5,1,0)) desc,  sum(IIF(point = 4,1,0)) desc";
```

Comment: One more thing sir, if i want to count total gold+total silver+total bronze ,then how can do that.Kindly help me.Thanx

Comment: I think you pretty much answered your own question.  Try that.

Comment: I did it Sir.Thanx a lot.